# Exporting forecast to a dataset while running a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to take one dataset and run a forecast on it based on different cutoffs. The for i runs, but it ends up saying "replacement has 76 rows, data has 0"

Here is the replicable example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(scales)
library(growthcurver)
options(scipen = 12) # Scientific Notation
options(digits = 6) # Specify Digits
noup<-3 #Days without update

claims <- tribble(~perdaycases, 3,1,1,0,0,0,
                       1,8, 7, 2,
                       8,  8, 12,
                       13, 15,
                       21, 27,
                       47, 65,
                       47, 30,
                       62, 74,
                       23, 38)

claims$cases <- cumsum(claims$perdaycases)
claims$id<-1:nrow(claims)

inds <- seq(as.Date("2020-03-11"), as.Date(Sys.Date()-noup), by = "day")

set.seed(1)
## Forecast length
h0 = 30

#Here, I create the empty dataset
estimates<-data.frame(Simulation=numeric(),Forecast=numeric()) #Empty Dataset

for(i in 1:length(claims$id)) {
  cap<-subset(claims,id<14+i) #First cutoff then it runs again
  cts <- ts(cap$cases, start = 1,frequency = 365) #Time Series
  cfore <- forecast(auto.arima(cts), h= h0, level = c(80)) #Do the Arima
  gc_fit <- SummarizeGrowth(seq(1,nrow(cap)),cap$cases) #Fit the Growth curve
  tt <- seq(from=nrow(cap)+1,to=90,by=1) 
  forelog <- predict(gc_fit$model,newdata=list(t=tt)) #Prediction 
  forecast<-forelog #Create the item with mean projection 
  len<-as.numeric(length(forecast)) #Length of each forecast
  estimates$Simulation<-as.numeric(rep(i,len)) #id each iteration 
  estimates$Forecast<-forecast #Here I try to export the forecast
}
```

The Error I get is ...

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Simulation", value = c(1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  replacement has 76 rows, data has 0

I am guessing it has to do with the last 2 lines but after 4 hours of struggling I have decided to ask for help.

SOS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide a minimal example that reproduces your error. Your problem boils down to this simple problem:

```
test <- data.frame(
  a=numeric(),
  b=numeric()
)

test$a <- c(1,2,3)
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, a, value = c(1, 2, 3)) : 
#  replacement has 3 rows, data has 0
```

Which doesn't work. You could do something like this:

```
test <- data.frame(
  a=numeric(),
  b=numeric()
)

for (i in 1:3){
  a <- c(rep(i, 3))
  b <- c(rep(i-1, 3))
  df <- data.frame(
    a = a,
    b = b
  )
  test <- bind_rows(test,df)
}
```

And for your specific example, you could replace the following lines:

```
  # estimates$Simulation <-as.numeric(rep(i,len)) #id each iteration 
  # estimates$Forecast<-forecast #Here I try to export the forecast

  df <- data.frame(
    Simulation = as.numeric(rep(i,len)),
    estimates = forecast
  )
  estimates <- bind_rows(estimates,df)
```